# form pot URL not defined in URLconf

Tags: django

I have a form that is on the URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/disciplineReport/1/ where 1 is the primary key of the object I'm editing.

detail.html:

```
<form method="post" id="edit-form" action="{% url 'disciplineReport:saveDiscipline' 
doctor.id %}}">
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
path('<int:pk>/saveDiscipline/', views.SaveDiscipline, name='saveDiscipline'),
]
```

Error:

```
Using the URLconf defined in program_history_reports.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

disciplineReport/ [name='index']
disciplineReport/ <int:pk>/ [name='detail']
disciplineReport/ <int:pk>/saveDiscipline/ [name='saveDiscipline']
admin/
The current path, disciplineReport/1/saveDiscipline/}, didn't match any of these.
```

What am I missing here? it seems like the URL matches the 3rd pattern...

Comment: You used `%}}`, so it has put a curly bracket at the end. It should be `%}`.

Answer (score 0):

before urlpatterns write this:

```
 app_name = 'disciplineReport'
```